How quickly did news travel in 12th century Eastern Europe?
I'm currently worldbuilding for a story set in the pre-Crusade Baltics, a couple of decades after the Crusades to the Holy Land had begun but half a century before the Crusader invasion of Baltic lands.
My premise is that news about the Crusades would reach the Baltics, and the protagonist, a far-seeing leader, would understand it's a threat to his people as well. But, naturally, the news reaching them would be delayed and distorted.
My question is,
How long would these delays realistically have been?

as news would be transported by people, you may use this answer as reference: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67455/travel-time-in-medieval-times

"a couple of decades after the Crusades to the Holy Land had begun but half a century before the Crusader invasion of Baltic lands"  – that does not add up. The first crusade to the Holy Land started in 1095, and the Northern crusades began fifty years later with the Wendish crusade 1147. And note that public calls for that crusade had been circulating at least since 1108 (the "Magdeburg Letter" mentioned in WP; the German WP article has a lot more details about it).

@DanM a ship from the Catholic bishop see of Kołobrzeg to Riga would have taken three days, max. I don't see that to be a major factor.

Not a bad question at all. This was well before the printing press, so making copies of written material was slow and expensive. Rumors can spread pretty quickly, but they aren't exactly known for accuracy. A pre-Christian baltic person wouldn't be tied into the main centralized literate information source in Europe, the Catholic Church.

Also, as I think about answering this, I'm finding a lot of speculative stuff that I'd like to say, but can't really because that stuff is off-topic here. I could perhaps still give it a try with what I can talk about, but are you sure you wouldn't rather ask this on World Building?

@ccprog the question is about holy land (which means Israel), but I agree with you that in the answer reported there was no mention of sail trips

Also to @ccprog's point about the timeline: A century before the First Crusade to the Holy Land, Adalbert of Prague tried to Christianize the Prussians and even that was perceived as a threat.  Rumors were probably being received from multiple sources/directions intermittently, long before the Wendish Crusade.  (Related question: Is the Wendish Crusade "Baltic" if the Wends were Slavs rather than Balts?)

@ccprog "The first crusade to the Holy Land started in 1095, and the Northern crusades began fifty years later with the Wendish crusade 1147." I know that. I meant German Crusaders arriving at Daugava estuary and beginning their campaigns here, which happened around the 1190s, then the founding of Riga in 1201.

Let's talk about what was going on in the Baltics in the 12th Century.
At this time There was a large somewhat coherent cultural group in the area speaking Baltic Languages. By this time the West Balts (in green shades in the picture) and the East Balts (in brown shades) likely could not understand each other easily, but within those divisions I'm not sure how mutually-intelligible the speech of the major tribes was. However, they clearly had their own culture with their own set of related languages and their own religion.

This entire area was illiterate*. This means there were in fact huge barriers to the transmission of what we'd consider "news" into, and even within, this area.
That being said, they did of course have some outside contact, but it seems to have been very ad-hoc. I dug up the following external contact with the (Old) Prussians in the 12th century:
in 1147 the High Duke of Poland, after years to border attacks, declared a Crusade against the Prussians. This went well enough that he was able to call on some Prussian support when Germany (The Holy Roman Empire) invaded the dutchy a decade later. However, a decade later another Polish army was destroyed trying to invade Prussia.
Then in the early 1190's Duke Casmir the Just invaded again. As you may gather from the name, he was also a big patron of the Catholic Church, which included setting up a branch of the (crusading) military order The Knights Hospitaler in Polish territory.

So what I'm seeing here is that it would be in fact very difficult for the largely illiterate and insular 12th Century West Balts to get timely accurate information about Christian Crusading activities in the Near East, which didn't really directly affect them. However, they would have been quite well-acquainted with the concept and danger posed by Crusades from the repeated attacks, some of which were labeled "Crusades", from their Polish neighbors.

* - This is in no way a cultural or ethnic dig, simply a historical fact. Today the Baltic nations are the most literate nations on earth

What you completely ignore is trade. At the top left of your map you see the island of Gotland, christianised in 1029. There is plenty of archeological evidence that its harbours at Paviken, Fröjel and Visby were exchanging goods with Baltic costal towns like Grobina/Seeburg or Truso. Do you really think they would not have talked about the political affairs in the countries they were trading with?...

...Another route to consider would be the one from the Varangians to the Greeks, with the western variant along the Vistula to the Danube or Dniester. Is there any reason to believe the Varangians would exclude the Balts from their trade or not talk to them?

What are your sources for the illiteracy claim?

Another point about trade. Arabs travelled that same Varangian-Greek route north-wards, mostly along the Daugava River and rivers connecting to it. There are Arab dirhems (silver coins) found in the territory of modern Latvia.

@ccprog - What organized trade was going on in this area at this time was at the hands of the Norse/Varangians. According to my handy New Penguin maps, they were in fact trading for silver and tin mined further upriver in modern Germany. The reason I'm skeptical that much news about goings on at the extreme other end of Christian Europe would have passed this way is that none of the sources I have found about the West Baltic people during this period seem to have been acquired via that route. Since its the same people going both ways, one could expect info to be traveling both ways equally.

@KrišjānisLiepiņš - There was no writing system for a Baltic language at this time. This is what we mean when we say a culture was "illiterate". Individual people may have known how to read and write in other languages, but for a culture to be "literate", it needs a writing system for its language (or to borrow both from another culture). For instance, the first written Old Prussian we have came in the 13th Century, after Christianization, and used the Latin alphabet. The Baltic legal codes were also entirely oral until that time.

Excuse me, but you are arguing like an apolget of colonialism: Since Europeans did not know anything about African history, negros must have been uncivilised and deserved to be lorded over. You fall just short of using this same structure to say that the Pope was right to call for the subjugation of the Balts into the Christian kingdoms.

@T.E.D. Recent (I don't know exactly how recent) archaeological findings indicate that the Balts had a writing system. Nothing much has survived till today because it was mostly written on perishable mediums, and after Christianization, there was no interest in preserving them, to say the least. But we know from what had been saved through oral retellings that Balts had people who specialised in working with writings. Secondly, most of the invading Crusaders were illiterate as they didn't know Latin script.

@KrišjānisLiepiņš - Got a reference for these findings? I'd love to read about them.

@T.E.D. I'll find and share them, but I don't have them right now.
